# SharePoint 2007 Force Culture and UI Culture

Tags: sharepoint-2007, localization, globalization, culture

i'm developing a sharepoint portal, and i want to force a portal culture to 'pt-PT', i already installed the moss and wss language packs and i changed the web.config too with the following statment:  but if i set the browser language to other language the controls change their culture (this only occurs in portal frontoffice, in backoffice the culture is always pt). What i have to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a HttpModule which will switch the culture of the executing HttpContext early in the page lifecycle.

BTW I'm just wondering what you mean when you say portal frontoffice vs backoffice.

Comment: When I refer to portal frontoffice is the pages that are accessible to the public (anonymous user) with a custom masterpage. The backoffice is all sharepoint's management pages. I understand your sugestion, but this should not be possible without having to write code? Just with configurations?

Comment: OK... As far as I know, the culture of a site is set when you create the site. If you have language packs installed, you create a site and specify what language that site is going to use. From that point, the site is always bound to that language, regardless of the user's browser setting.